# @{View.GONE}/@{View.INVISIBLE} doesn't change anything in xml

Tags: android

I have created an empty project, enabled data binding:

```
buildFeatures {
        dataBinding true
    }
```

Then I've converted the default layout to data binding layout, and imported View type. But the following code doesn't change the visibility of the element:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <import type="android.view.View"/>
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World!"
            android:visibility="@{View.INVISIBLE}"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

But `android:visibility="@{View.INVISIBLE}"` doesn't make the TextView invisible. Changing this line to `android:visibility="invisible"` works properly. What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:**
I'm using this guide:
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions#imports_variables_and_includes

Comment: You never bind any data, there is no event to prompt that data to bind to the view. The documentation you reference uses an observer style data binding that in turn prompts a tenary function

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've binded data and everything's fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you look into the source code, you will find the value of `View.INVISIBLE` as follows

```java
/**
     * This view is invisible, but it still takes up space for layout purposes.
     * Use with {@link #setVisibility} and <a href="#attr_android:visibility">{@code
     * android:visibility}.
     */
    public static final int INVISIBLE = 0x00000004;
```

While if you look in to XML source code, you will find its value as this

```xml
 <!-- Controls the initial visibility of the view.  -->
        <attr name="visibility">
            <!-- Visible on screen; the default value. -->
            <enum name="visible" value="0" />
            <!-- Not displayed, but taken into account during layout (space is left for it). -->
            <enum name="invisible" value="1" />
            <!-- Completely hidden, as if the view had not been added. -->
            <enum name="gone" value="2" />
        </attr>
```

So as they are both different values. When you set the code value it does not work.

Comment: According to this document:
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions#imports_variables_and_includes
it must work as expected. Why doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

When the values from XML are read, the visibility tag expects an enum from `visible`, `invisible`, or `gone`. Based on the value given, the appropriate visibility flags are set for the view. `View.INVISIBLE` won't work since it resolves to the actual flag value i.e. `public static final int INVISIBLE = 0x00000004;`. You can use this in Java code by `textView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)`

**Edit:**

For data binding to work, the view should be inflated using Data Binding. The Activity's onCreate() should be:

```
private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(LayoutInflator.from(this))
    setContentView(binding.root)
}
```

Comment: It actually does work if you bind data to the data binding layout, I just tested it and it works just fine.  It uses expression language and some data binding magic under the hood: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions